# How include window.load or $( document ).ready() in this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, I dont have enough javascript skills to modify this code.

The function is triggered when `blur change keyup`events are fired. But ALSO I need the function triggered on `window.load` or `$( document ).ready()`.

Someone please can change the code below to work in this scenario?

```
$cep.on('blur change keyup', function() {
    var val = $cep.val();
    // Remove caracteres que o usuario normalmente digita no cep como - e .
    val = val.replace(/\-|\./g, "");
    if (val && currentCep !== val && val.length === 8) {
        currentCep = val;
        self.sendRequest();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read about **[function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)**, which its can resolve issue, and its one of basic programming rule, so that your issue will be resolved by this:

```
$cep.on('blur change keyup', function() {
    myFunctionName();
}); 

$(myFunctionName); 
// its the same $( document ).ready(myFunctionName);

    function myFunctionName(){
var val = $cep.val();
        // Remove caracteres que o usuario normalmente digita no cep como - e .
        val = val.replace(/\-|\./g, "");
        if (val && currentCep !== val && val.length === 8) {
            currentCep = val;
            self.sendRequest();
        }
}
```

Last thing, you can try and post your issue when trying code, nested of ask to write code, since its not truth in this community. good luck.

@thanks for CertainPerformance & Shikkediel

Comment: No need for an anonymous wrapper for `myFunctionName` - you can just pass `myFunctionName` alone

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){myFunctionName();});` is the same as `$(myFunctionName);`. The latter is the [recommended](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) way, all others are deprecated.

Comment: Thats true @CertainPerformance & Shikkediel, thanks for sharing, just I try to explain it .

Answer (score 0):

Base on Anees answer, I made it work this way, without changing the original code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById("cep").focus();    
        document.getElementById("cep").blur();    
    });
</script>
```